# Can't set charge_control_start_threshold and charge_control_end_threshold to distinct values

Tags: kernel, thinkpad, battery

I'm trying to set battery thresholds on a Thinkpad laptop. I'm executing the following two commands:

```
echo 45 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_start_threshold
echo 50 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold
```

However, when executing the second command, it also changes the value of `charge_control_start_threshold` to 50, so I'm unable to write distinct values to the two files.

Linux kernel is 6.4.6.

Do you know what could be the cause? Maybe I misunderstood what those two files do and/or how they work.

Thanks.